# How To Read an HTML File from another url using webrequest using c#

Tags: c#

I need to use the below call first. I will get

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/DxLogin?userid={userid}&PW={password}0&hdnBusiness={facilityid}&target=jsp/lab/results/FDC.jsp&apiLogin=true&apiuserid={userid}&actionCommand=startDownload&autoPrint=true&batchDownload=true&reportTypes=LABRES&CreationDateFrom=02/01/2013&CreationDateTo=04/24/2013");
    WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

    WebRequest request1 = WebRequest.Create("https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/lab.results.fdcServlet?actionCommand=NextFile&batchDownload=true&fdcuserid={userid}");

    WebResponse resp1 = request.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream1 = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseReader1 = new StreamReader(responseStream1);
    string responseString1 = responseReader1.ReadToEnd();


    WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/lab.results.fdcServlet?actionCommand=GetFileInfo&fdcuserid={userid}");
    WebResponse resp2 = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream2 = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseReader2 = new StreamReader(responseStream2);
    string responseString2 = responseReader2.ReadToEnd();


    WebRequest request3 = WebRequest.Create("https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/lab.results.fdcServlet?actionCommand=DownloadFile&mmi=true&fdcuserid={userid}");
    WebResponse resp3 = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream3 = resp3.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseReader3 = new StreamReader(responseStream3);
    string responseString3 = responseReader3.ReadToEnd();

    WebRequest request4 = WebRequest.Create("https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/lab.results.fdcServlet?actionCommand=MarkAsDownloaded&fdcuserid={userid}");
    WebResponse resp4 = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream4 = resp4.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseReader4 = new StreamReader(responseStream3);
    string responseString4 = responseReader4.ReadToEnd();
    resp.Close();
    resp1.Close();
    resp2.Close();
    resp3.Close();
    resp4.Close();
```

Note: {userid},{password},{facilityId} are credentials to login.

```
I need to call all the 5 request and parse it and save. I need to call each calls by listed order only.
```

1) First call I am getting the expected output.
  2) Call expected is "<--BEGIN NUMBER OF DOCS>2;warning;123345;asdf;sdf;234243;18872_TEST_TC3;<--END NUMBER OF DOCS>"  but my stream reader getting empty.

3) all the other calls getting empty

Any suggestion to read and solutions are welcome. I am new bee to development and c#.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Rajesh.k

Comment: Be careful about transmitting login credentials in a GET request because of server logs.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same responseStream "resp" on all your calls instead of each subsequent resp1, resp2, etc, variables, and the same with response and other vars:

```
Stream responseStream2 = resp.GetResponseStream();
```

Check your code before posting, please...